# How do I create pipeline variables for a YAML-based pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With designer/class build pipeline, you can define pipeline variables with default values to be passed into the tasks. How do I do the same for a YAML-based pipeline?

I want to create three build pipelines, each would have a single variable set to a different value. All three point to a single YAML file. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) states:

> You can choose which variables are allowed to be set at queue time and which are fixed by the pipeline author. If a variable appears in the variables block of a YAML file, it is fixed and cannot be overridden at queue time. To allow a variable to be set at queue time, make sure it doesn't appear in the variables block of a pipeline or job. You can set a default value in the editor, and that value can be overridden by the person queuing the pipeline.

It's not clear how to do this for YAML file.

I can create a template YAML file, and an individual YAML file for each config value that calls the template file, but then I can't set configuration value at run-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you edit the build definition (not when you create it, at least with default experience). you'd need to click on 3 dots and pick `variables` from the list:

[image]

and there you would be able to define variables, and they would have a checkbox - `Settable at queue time`.

Comment: Just to clarify in case anyone else comes across this, it seems like you can't define the variables in the YAML file and you have to instead use the UI (which you can only get to after you've checked in an initial copy of the azure-pipeline.yml file)

Comment: i think they allow setting variables in yaml now, recent sprint introduced that

Comment: It would be great if they did - do you have a link to the documentation about how to do it?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-in-azure-devops-sprint-155/

Comment: Looks like they've just unlocked editing them in a different UI, but you still can't declare them directly in the .yml file.

Comment: ugh, okay, sorry misunderstood that article title ;)